# How can we using delete operation for deleting a row in a table using three primary keys.Is there anyway to delete

Tags: mysql

i have tried using this way---

```
delete from table 
where 
  primarykey(int)=123 and 
  primarykey(field)='field1' and 
  primarykey(date)=2011-09-08;
```

it return

> 0 rows affected and 2 warnings.

Comment: Did you check the SELECT query with the same conditions?

Comment: attache `show warnings;` results into your question (right after execution of your query)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works better:

```
delete from table  
where  
  int=123 and  
  field='field1' and  
  date=2011-09-08;
```

assuming that the fields in table are named like int, field and date.

Comment: Thanks to you all.you guys helped me in figuring out the problem.Its solved.Thanks Hatch,Doug Kress.

Answer (score 1):

A table can only have a single primary key (although it can have multiple unique keys). Are you suggesting a delete with three conditions?

I recommend writing your delete statement out as a select statement first. For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field1 = 123 AND field2 = 'abc' and field3 = '2011-09-08';
```

If that returns the desired result, just change the `SELECT *` to `DELETE`:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE field1 = 123 AND field2 = 'abc' and field3 = '2011-09-08';
```

Answer (score 0):

You looking for something like this?

```
DELETE from table WHERE columnA = '123' AND columnB = 'field' AND columnC = '2011-09-08'
```